# iOS UILabel font scaling not working after changing line height

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

I am trying to have a UILabel change size of font within to fit all text within it on each device resolution.  The width of the label is fixed based proportionally on superview width; so on smaller devices the text must scale down to fit properly.

This works fine when I am creating labels with 'Line - Height Multiple' set to default 0, but if I modify that number at all the text in the UILabel will not scale down and instead truncate the tail.

Constraints are the proportional width as stated above and also center alignment of horizontal and vertical based on superview.

Text: Attributed, 
Autoshrink: Minimum Font Size, 
Line Break: Truncate Tail, 
Lines: 2, 
Xcode 11

Is there a way to stop the truncation and get font scaling working with the Line Height value changed?  I would like to get this working from Interface Builder and not from code if possible.

Edit: I found that after I change the line height value that the Autoshrink value changes by itself back to 'Fixed Font Size'.  So I guess this simply is not allowed.  Does anyone know the proper method of solving this scenario using interface builder?